# Version number of new entity is equal to 1 after first save

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I'm really confused about saving new entity to repository.

Firstly I check `repo.findAll()` to see element inside, and lets say there is one element there.
Then,  I save entity like SomEntity(id=1, version=0, name="SomeName") to repository.
Next I check again `repo.findAll()` and I get 2 elements and my new saved entity is like `SomEntity(id=1, version=1, name="SomeName")`.

I do not get it. Why version is 1? Why not 0?

I tried to debug inside some spring modules, but it's really hard to debug it. I could only observe that inside SimpleJpaRepository:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
   Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null.");
   if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
       this.em.persist(entity);
       return entity;
   } else {
       return this.em.merge(entity);
   }
}
```

it goes to `this.em.merge(entity)` as it contains already id.

I could see that if if I run line `transaction.save(entity)` in return I get entity with version 0, but if I run repo.findAll() I see that entity with version 1.

Could someone explain me this?

Comment: Can you show us what `this.entityInformation.isNew` does?

Comment: @EricGeorge it's from spring module. Not my code. It checks if id is null or not.

Comment: We still need more of your code to understand what might be happening? Please include the code of yours that is executing during the failure condition.